# Why getting reference binding to null-pointer error?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, error-handling, runtime-error

I am solving the following Leetcode problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-if-path-exists-in-graph/

I am getting the following error:

```
Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
```

The code for my approach:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void dfs(int *visited,int node,vector<vector<int>>&adj)
    {
        visited[node]=1;
        for(auto child:adj[node])
        {
            if(visited[child]==-1)
                dfs(visited,child,adj);
        }
    }
    bool validPath(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, int source, int destination) {
        vector<vector<int>>adj;
        for(auto it:edges)
        {
            adj[it[0]].push_back(it[1]);
            
        }
        int visited[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            visited[i]=-1;
        
        dfs(visited,source,adj);
        
        return visited[destination]==1;
    }
};
```

I'm getting this error for almost every graph problem. Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: where does edges come from?

Comment: @user253751 it comes from user input which I dont have to deal with.

Comment: is it null....?

Comment: @user253751   Probably not,,also I just have to implement the function on leetcode why deal with inputs?

Comment: Difficult to say without a [mre] but at a guess one of your vector accesses is out of bounds. Try using a debugger and/or replacing `[]` with `at`

Comment: Note that `int visited[n]` isn't valid c++, you should use `std::vector` instead

Comment: @AlanBirtles still getting the error after using vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer vector of **adj** should be resized, before adding elements to the inner vector.

```
bool validPath(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, int source, int destination) {
    vector<vector<int>>adj;
    for(auto& it:edges)
    {
        if (adj.size() < (it[0] + 1))
        {
            adj.resize(it[0] + 1);    
        }
        
        adj[it[0]].push_back(it[1]);
            
    }
    
    //Rest of the code  
}
```